# Unable to save meta data via the "woocommerce_product_set_stock" hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to update a product meta data: `_alg_wc_pq_max` in WooCommerce when the stock changes, but it is not updated.

My code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'stock_changed' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'stock_changed' );
function stock_changed( $product ) {
    $product->update_meta_data('_alg_wc_pq_max', 100);
    $product->save_meta_data();
}
```

I also tried instead of:

```
$product->update_meta_data( '_alg_wc_pq_max', $max_vas_menny ):
```

To use:

```
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_alg_wc_pq_max', $max_vas_menny );
```

And:

```
update_metadata( 'post', $product_id, '_alg_wc_pq_max', $max_vas_menny );
```

But all without the desired result.

---

If I used `$product->save()` instead of `product->save_meta_data()` then the "Edit product" page stucks after changing the stock, according to log it makes an infinite loop (save() recalls the "stock_changed" function).

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use another hook, if it is hook dependent you can use an SQL query.

Then you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_product_set_stock ( $product_with_stock ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get product ID
    $product_id = $product_with_stock->get_id();

    $wpdb->query( "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
        SET meta_value = '100'
        WHERE meta_key = '_alg_wc_pq_max'
        AND post_id = '$product_id'
    " );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'action_woocommerce_product_set_stock', 10, 1 );
```